# How can I execute my code after data load is finished on my react project

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, error-handling

I am creating a graph chart using chart js. My problem is the code is running before the data is loading that's why I am getting errors. I want after the data load the code will execute, I used loading state but it's not working also used optional chaining.

Data fetching code is

```
   useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('./fakeDta.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setSchedules(data))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }, [])
```

The errors are

`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

The main error is here:

```
 const chart2 = schedulesByDate(date)
 Object?.entries(chart2)?.map(
        ([key, value]) => {
            dateLabels.push(key);
            previousDateSchedules.push(value)

        }
```

Full code

```
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import './chart.css'
Chart.register(...registerables);


function BarChart() {
    const inputRef1 = useRef()
    const [date, setDate] = useState('')
    const [laoding, setLoading] = useState(false)

    // First chart date labels and value
    let dateLabels = []
    let previousDateSchedules = []

    // Data
    const [schedules, setSchedules] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('./fakeDta.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setSchedules(data))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }, [])

    // Bar chart option
    let options = {
        scales: {
            y: {
                max: 10,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }
        }
    };


    // Chart 1 Function Start
    const schedulesByDate = (date) => {
        let dbItemDate = date;
        let otherDayArray = schedules?.filter(num => num.item_date < dbItemDate);
        let count = otherDayArray?.reduce(function (acc, num) {

            acc[num.item_date] = (acc[num.item_date] || 0) + 1;
            return acc;
        }, []);
        console.log(count);//this should print the frequency of each date in the others date array 
        return count


    }

    const chart2 = schedulesByDate(date)

    Object?.entries(chart2)?.map(
        ([key, value]) => {
            dateLabels.push(key);
            previousDateSchedules.push(value)

        }
    )
    // Chart 1 Function End


    //function to get Chart 2 result
    let getScheduleCounter = (date) => {
        let scheduleCounter = {
            '9_12': [],
            '12_3': [],
            '3_6': [],
            '6_9': []
        };

        schedules.forEach(sch => {
            if (sch.item_date === date) {
                updateScheduledCounter(sch, scheduleCounter);
            }
        });

        return scheduleCounter;
    }

    //function to get the count and update in scheduleCounter 
    let updateScheduledCounter = (sch, scheduleCounter) => {
        let time = sch.schedule_time.split(' ')[1];
        switch (!!time) {
            case (time <= '12:00:00'):
                scheduleCounter['9_12']++;
                break;

            case (time >= '12:00:00' && time <= '15:00:00'):
                scheduleCounter['12_3']++;
                break;

            case (time >= '15:00:00' && time <= '18:00:00'):
                scheduleCounter['3_6']++;
                break;

            case (time >= '18:00:00' && time <= '21:00:00'):
                scheduleCounter['6_9']++;
                break;
        }
    }

    let schedulesTimes = []
    let schedulesTimesValues = []

    let schedule = getScheduleCounter(date);
    console.log('schedules: ', schedule);


    Object.entries(schedule).map(
        ([key, value]) => {
            schedulesTimes.push(key);
            schedulesTimesValues.push(value)

        }
    )

    console.log(schedulesTimes, schedulesTimesValues);



    return (
        <>
            {
                laoding ? <h2>loading....</h2> : <div className="container">

                    <div className="bar">
                        <div classNam="chart-container" style={{ position: "relative", height: "550px", width: "40vw" }}>
                            <h2>Item Dates</h2>
                            <Bar
                                id="myChart"

                                data={{
                                    labels: dateLabels,
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Scheduled',
                                        data: previousDateSchedules,
                                        backgroundColor: [
                                            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                                        ],
                                        borderColor: [
                                            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
                                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                                        ],
                                        borderWidth: 1
                                    }]
                                }}

                                options={options}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="chart-container" style={{ position: "relative", height: "550px", width: "40vw" }}>
                            <h2>{date} Schedules</h2>
                            <Bar
                                id="myChart"
                                data={{
                                    labels: ['9am to 12pm', '12pm to 3pm', '3pm to 6pm', '6pm to 9pm'],
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Scheduled',
                                        data: schedulesTimesValues,
                                        backgroundColor: [
                                            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                                        ],
                                        borderColor: [
                                            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
                                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                                        ],
                                        borderWidth: 1
                                    }]
                                }}

                                options={options}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <input type="date" ref={inputRef1} defaultValue='2021-05-18' />
                        <button onClick={() => setDate(inputRef1.current.value)}>Filter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default BarChart;
```

Comment: You're doing a lot of code that looks like it should only execute once per mount outside of a `useEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that might be causing the problem:

1. Typo for loading in code, you have `laoding` but it should be `loading`. However this isn't likely a big issue as you still try to access schedule data higher up in your code before it has been set to the result of your fetch.
2. For readability, update your ternary to wrap the results of:
   `<div className="container"> ...`  in brackets
3. The `fetch` function is async and returns a promise, meaning you'll have to wrap your fetch call in the useEffect in an async function:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
  const fetchData = async () => {
     fetch('./fakeDta.json')
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(data => setSchedules(data))
           .finally(() => setLoading(false))
   };

   fetchData();
 },[])
```

4. Under your use effect I would check that schedule actually has data, before preforming actions on it (as it'll cause those errors you're getting if schedule is empty) - something like:

```
if(!schedule){
  return <div>Loading</div>
}
```